# Calculating distance between two points on map using ITM coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, distance

How to calculate the distance between two point on the map using ITM coords?

i have a map with items on it all with ITM coords and i need to return all items in X meters of radius from my location.

the problem is how to convert the distance between the two points on the map to meters or km.

Comment: If you mean the Irish transverse mercator projection, then the coordinates are already in meters http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Transverse_Mercator hence standard euclidean calculations would apply

Answer (score 2):

As Dan mentioned you should simply be able to view those measurements as is, depending on how you are calculating the distances. Simply using the measure tool between the points will give you the distance between them and can be viewed in any metric. If you're generating distances in your attribute table, then simply creating another field to convert those generated distances would work as well.